# Java Sockets Can't Access Server using Subnet IP Address

Tags: java, sockets, java-10

Using JDK 10, am trying to write a client / server program that will run separately on multiple computers using TCP/IP sockets.

All computers should be in same local subnet 192.168.1.x (where x can be varied between 1 and 254).

The individual servers receive a string from the client program and print out the string.

ServerThread.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;

    public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Connected" + socket);
        try {
            var in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            var out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                out.println(in.nextLine());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + socket);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Closed: " + socket);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (var listener = new ServerSocket(6500)) {
            System.out.println("Server has started...");
            var pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
            while (true) {
                pool.execute(new ServerThread(listener.accept()));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

Originally, it would work with `"localhost"` as the hostName:

```
public class Client {

    public static void connect(String hostName, String portNumber) throws Exception {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(portNumber);
        try (var socket = new Socket(hostName, port)) {
            System.out.println("Enter lines of text then Ctrl+D or Ctrl+C to quit");
            var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            var in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            var out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.println(in.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Client.connect("localhost", "6500");
    }
}
```

---

Now when using `new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress), port)`, I get `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` Exception:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    public static void connect(String iPAddress, String portNumber) throws Exception {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(portNumber);

        try (var socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(iPAddress), port)) {
            System.out.println("Enter lines of text then Ctrl+D or Ctrl+C to quit");
            var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            var in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            var out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.println(in.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Client.connect("192.168.1.1", "6500");
    }
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:540)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:436)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:246)
    at com.sample.Client.connect(Client.java:13)
    at com.sample.Client.main(Client.java:26)
```

---

However, when I try using `"192.168.1.2"`, nothing happens (it doesn't even print out: `Enter lines of text then Ctrl+D or Ctrl+C to quit`)

And eventually, it times out by throwing this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:540)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:436)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:246)
    at com.sample.Client.connect(Client.java:13)
    at com.sample.Client.main(Client.java:26)
```

---

Questions:

1. Why is it throwing this exception: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` when using `192.168.1.1` and `java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)` when using any digit other than 1 for the host (last digit), e.g. `192.168.1.2` ?
2. Is there some other Java 10 API (e.g. reactive streams or NIO channels) that is better than just using Threads for the Server?

Comment: 'Connection refused' has exactly one meaning: nothing was listening at the host:port or IP address:port you tried to connect to. So either you hadn't started the server or you got its address:port wrong in the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - my router / firewall assigns different computers inside my network to different Subnet based IP addresses but doesn't necessarily will assign the second computer (subsequentially) to:

`191.168.1.2`

Ran an `ifconfig` and discovered the particular Subnet based IP address which was `192.168.1.x` the real value of "x" was omitted for security reasons.

Comment: There is no security reason. Nobody can access your private subnet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also be aware of some system tools to debug at a black box level about your application in order to figure out possible issues:

I am a Linux person, so know only about Linux utilities:

"sudo netstat -tpln" to find out if your server application is listening on the desired port, and most importantly it should be listening on the IP 0.0.0.0 and not just 127.0.0.1 in order for network computers to be able to connect to it.

"sudo iptables -vnL" to find out if the firewall is not blocking external originated connections to your server applications. If this is the case, then client app on the same system where your server app resides will be able to communicate, but not the same client app on other systems on the same network.

In my experience these debugging helps resolve such issues in more than 90% of time and it is usually not a programming issue. I hope this info helps.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake is to assume that `Socket` constructor uses both IP and hostname, in reality:

```
new Socket("192.168.1.2", 6500)
```

doesn't work because it expects hostname. From [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) doc:

```
host - the host name, or null for the loopback address.
. . .
public Socket(String host,int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
```

What you have to use is:

```
new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2"), 6500)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are parsing the docs more finely than is warranted.  There is every reason to expect that `Socket(String, int)` will convert the hostname string presented to it to an `InetAddress` via `InetAddress.getByName()`, exactly as you suggest the OP do manually.

Comment: @rxn1d - thank but now its throwing a ```java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused ``` for 192.168.1.1 and ```java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out``` for any other subnet host (e.g. 192.168.1.2). edited my post to reflect this...

Comment: Do you have a firewall? Usually, the firewall blocks any attempt of TCP connection being initialized outside of the host itself. If you have it on the server machine, try disable it for this specific port.

Comment: @JohnBollinger is quite right. You can specify either a hostname or an IP address. This has been working for at least 23 years. Answer is not correct.